# Expand end divs to fill remaining space

Tags: html, css

I have the following:

```css
#subsystemTabs{
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-flow: center;
}

#rightPad, #leftPad{
  height: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  border: solid;
  flex-grow: 100;
}

.subsystemTab{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  border: solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="subsystemTabs">
  <div id="rightPad"></div>
  <div class="subsystemTab"></div>
  <div class="subsystemTab"></div>
  <div class="subsystemTab"></div>
  <div class="subsystemTab"></div>
  <div class="subsystemTab"></div>
  <div class="subsystemTab"></div>
  <div class="subsystemTab"></div>
  <div id="leftPad"></div>
</div>
```

I want the two end boxes #rightPad and #leftPad to expand to fill the rest of the container. I have used flex-grow: 100; on the two end divs and this works, but I don't feel that it is correct, because theoretically if the page was massive the two end divs would eventually stop growing.

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you tried using nth-child?

Comment: [See if this helps](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex-grow/)

Answer (score 0):

```
.subsystemTabs:first-child{
 height: 50px;
 margin: auto;
 border: solid;
 padding-left: 50px; //lets say
}
.subsystemTabs:last-child{
 height: 50px;
 margin: auto;
 border: solid;
 padding-right: 50px; //lets say
}
```

i dont think this is the exact padding this is just to give u an idea how can you make it right.

Answer (score 0):

if you wish to use flex, stop trying to control widths, it kind of defeats the purpose of "flexible" but if you must set widths, use min/max-width css.

As you can see [here @ CSSTricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex-grow/), the flex-grow number is a ratio.  But is subject to the container width and fixed width elements

```css
#subsystemTabs, #subsystemTabs2, #subsystemTabs3{
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-flow: center;
}
#subsystemTabs2{
   width: 80%;
}
#subsystemTabs3{
   width: 50%;
}


#rightPad, #leftPad{
  height: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  border: solid;
  flex-grow: 2;
}

.subsystemTab{
  max-width: 50px;
  min-width:50px;
  height: 50px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: blue;
  border: solid;
}

.subsystemTab2{
  height: 50px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: blue;
  border: solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="subsystemTabs">
  <div id="rightPad"></div>
  <div class="subsystemTab"></div>
  <div class="subsystemTab"></div>
  <div class="subsystemTab"></div>
  <div class="subsystemTab"></div>
  <div class="subsystemTab"></div>
  <div class="subsystemTab"></div>
  <div class="subsystemTab"></div>
  <div id="leftPad"></div>
</div>

<div id="subsystemTabs2">
  <div id="rightPad"></div>
  <div class="subsystemTab"></div>
  <div class="subsystemTab"></div>
  <div class="subsystemTab"></div>
  <div class="subsystemTab"></div>
  <div class="subsystemTab"></div>
  <div class="subsystemTab"></div>
  <div class="subsystemTab"></div>
  <div id="leftPad"></div>
</div>

<div id="subsystemTabs3">
  <div id="rightPad"></div>
  <div class="subsystemTab2"></div>
  <div class="subsystemTab2"></div>
  <div class="subsystemTab2"></div>
  <div class="subsystemTab2"></div>
  <div class="subsystemTab2"></div>
  <div class="subsystemTab2"></div>
  <div class="subsystemTab2"></div>
  <div id="leftPad"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use : `flex:1;` only on containers that needs to fill up space left.

if you set `margin:auto;` element will shrink and center themselves, don't and you  won't have to set any size.

You may also use a `min-width` instead a `width` on childs.

If you need to set an `height`, you can do it on the parent, element will size themselves to this this `height`. `min-height` can also be used. If it was for demo, you can remove it, the tallest element will be the height of the whole row.

```css
#subsystemTabs{
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-flow: center;
  height: 50px;
}

#rightPad, #leftPad{
  border: solid;
  flex:1;
  background:yellow;
}

.subsystemTab{
  min-width: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  border: solid black;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<div id="subsystemTabs">
  <div id="rightPad"></div>
  <div class="subsystemTab">sys 1</div>
  <div class="subsystemTab">2</div>
  <div class="subsystemTab">here is the third</div>
  <div class="subsystemTab">and 4</div>
  <div class="subsystemTab">and then 5</div>
  <div class="subsystemTab"> 6 ?</div>
  <div class="subsystemTab">Seven the last !</div>
  <div id="leftPad"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would to it like this. first remove the flex propreties and the fixed width from class subsystemTab, and add instad procentual width for id leftPad, rightPad and class subsystemTab. And use `box-sizing: border-box;`

```
#subsystemTabs{
  width: 100%;
}

#rightPad, #leftPad{
  height: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 15%;
  border: solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  float:left
}

.subsystemTab{
  width: 10%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  border: solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  float:left
}
```